# Extending vs. Subclassing in Objective-C, Which is better for creating a calculator class that I want to extend later?

Tags: objective-c, ios, design-patterns

I'm creating a calculator class and I want to be able to extend it in the future. I can't decide if I should have future classes subclass it, or if I should just have each extension be a new category. Which is the better option?

I can't decide what the best way for someone to extend this calculator class, if I wanted to add on to it in the future. Should I have each user subclass it, or add a category of methods that they want to add.

What I wanted to do is if the user wants to define a new operation say "+*", they could define it in a new category and give me a selector, so I could store all operations in a Dictionary and pick which method to compute the result.

For example,

`SEL method = NSSelectorFromString (
    @"plusTimesWithArgA:andArgB:";
);`

`[self performSelector:@selector(method) withObject:operandA withObject:operandB];`

Comment: From what you said in the later part of your question and the example, it looks like category is the way to go with.  Since  users are not needing to overwrite any methods in your class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) pattern. Subclassing is the tightest form of coupling. Extending the class carries risk of overriding existing methods and creates a high amount of coupling.

With Visitor the pattern you can have a method that takes the id of an object that should have the an "operate" method. It can operate in any way as long as it takes the input and returns a result. This means you can implement unlimited operations with no knowledge of the rest of the calculator class.